# Framer motion doesn't animate element on exit

Tags: reactjs, react-router, framer-motion

I'm trying to animate the name of my pages. It's a React application using react-router and framer motion.
In the code below, the `<h1>` content changes relative to the pathname. It works well except for the exit animation which is not triggered.

I read the framer documentation and googled for fix and finally checked those points:

Element to exit must be direct child of  - done.
Element must have a unique key - done using useLocation() hook.

With that in mind, I wrote this:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { motion, AnimatePresence  } from "framer-motion";

function Header() {

    const location = useLocation()

    return (
        <header id="content-header">

            <div className="card" id="page-title">
                <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
                    
                    <motion.h1
                        key={location.pathname}
                        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: '100%' }}
                        animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                        exit={{ opacity: 0, y: '-100%' }}
                        transition={{
                            ease: "linear",
                            duration: 2,
                        }}
                    >
                        { location.pathname === '/' ? 'Dashboard' : location.pathname.substring(1) }
                    </motion.h1>
                    
                </AnimatePresence>
            </div>

        </header>
    );
}

export default Header
```

But the exit animation doesn't trigger. Can some one help?
Thank you !

Comment: The Framer code works fine (https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dew-75y8h6?file=/src/Header.jsx). If you've checked that you're getting the proper strings for `location.pathname`, maybe the Header component itself is getting removed from the DOM when the route changes?

Comment: "Thank you @Cadin, the problem comes from there. I refactored my code to take the header out of the part updated by React Router. It works very well now!"

Answer (score 0):

AnimatePresence makes exit animation when element is conditional rendered.

Solution:

```
<AnimatePresence AnimatePresence mode="wait" >
    {/* conditional rendering component */}
    {active && (

        <motion.h1
            key={location.pathname}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: '100%' }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, y: '-100%' }}
            transition={{
                ease: "linear",
                duration: 2,
            }}
        >
            {location.pathname === '/' ? 'Dashboard' : location.pathname.substring(1)}
        </motion.h1>
    )}

</AnimatePresence>
```

Reference: [Framer motion AnimatePresence](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/)